# how to get rid of email disclaimers when parsing

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am working on getting emails out of inbox in the Exchange Web server 2010. As many different organizations are expected to send in mails, is there a way to get/parse the stupid disclaimers out while parsing emails. I am looking to weed out any silly format of disclaimers.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trial and error? Get a sample together and create a method that satisfies the sample. You'll never get 100% accurate, but you can get within an acceptable/tolerable range. From there, you keep adding exceptions, specific conditions, etc.

Keep in mind companies spend millions on information parsing (such as adddresses, telephone numbers, etc.), so you're not alone on the difficulty scale.